# How can I display annotations for multiple hospitals in the region using MapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am trying to display only hospitals in a map View, but I can´t make it work. How can I do that? Please help. Currently, I am using annotations and programming them individually to achieve this, that is why I want a faster way to show all hospitals in the area. The part that is commented is my code to try and search for the hospitals and then show them, but I only get one annotation and I want multiple annotations.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  aidkit
//
//  Created by Roberto Guarneros on 1/18/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Roberto Guarneros. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapScreen: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var goButton: UIButton!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let regionInMeters: Double = 5000
    var previousLocation: CLLocation?

    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    var directionsArray: [MKDirections] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkLocationServices()
    }

    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }


    func centerViewOnUserLocation() {
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }


    func checkLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuthorization()
        } else {
            // Show alert letting the user know they have to turn this on.
        }
    }


    func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            startTackingUserLocation()
        case .denied:
            // Show alert instructing them how to turn on permissions
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            // Show an alert letting them know what's up
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            break
        }
    }


    func startTackingUserLocation() {
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        centerViewOnUserLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        previousLocation = getCenterLocation(for: mapView)
    }


    func getCenterLocation(for mapView: MKMapView) -> CLLocation {
        let latitude = mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude
        let longitude = mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude

        return CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }


    func getDirections() {
        guard let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate else {
            //TODO: Inform user we don't have their current location
            return
        }

        let request = createDirectionsRequest(from: location)
        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
        resetMapView(withNew: directions)

        directions.calculate { [unowned self] (response, error) in
            //TODO: Handle error if needed
            guard let response = response else { return } //TODO: Show response not available in an alert

            for route in response.routes {
                self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline)
                    self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect, animated: true)
            }
        }
     }


     func createDirectionsRequest(from coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> MKDirections.Request {
        let destinationCoordinate       = getCenterLocation(for: mapView).coordinate
        let startingLocation            = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate)
        let destination                 = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCoordinate)

        let request                     = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source                  = MKMapItem(placemark: startingLocation)
        request.destination             = MKMapItem(placemark: destination)
        request.transportType           = .automobile
        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true

        return request
     }


     func resetMapView(withNew directions: MKDirections) {
        mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays)
        directionsArray.append(directions)
        let _ = directionsArray.map { $0.cancel() }
     }

     @IBAction func goButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        getDirections()
        print("hello")
     }

    //    func startSearchingForHospitals(){
    //        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    //
    //        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    //        activityIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
    //        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    //        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    //        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    //
    //        self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    //
    //        let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
    //        searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "Hospital"
    //
    //        let activeSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
    //
    //        activeSearch.start { ( response, error) in
    //            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    //            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    //
    //
    //            if response == nil{
    //                print("Error")
    //            } else {
    //                let annotations = self.mapView.annotations
    //                self.mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)
    //
    //                let latitude = response?.boundingRegion.center.latitude
    //                let longitude = response?.boundingRegion.center.longitude
    //
    //                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    //                annotation.title = "Hospital"
    //                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)
    //    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    //
    //            }
    //        }
    //




      private func addAnnotations(){
        let hospitalLaPaz = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalLaPaz.title = "Hospital La Paz"
        hospitalLaPaz.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.058851, longitude: -98.226132)

        let hospitalSalutem = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalSalutem.title = "Hospital Salutem"
        hospitalSalutem.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.058962, longitude: -98.230976)

        let hospitalPuebla = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalPuebla.title = "Hospital Puebla"
        hospitalPuebla.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.030592, longitude: -98.229141)

        let hospitalAngeles = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalAngeles.title = "Hospital Ángeles-Puebla"
        hospitalAngeles.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.021676, longitude: -98.235278)

        let hospitalDelNiñoPoblano = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalDelNiñoPoblano.title = "Hospital del Niño Poblano"
        hospitalDelNiñoPoblano.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.034798, longitude: -98.244053)

        let hospitalBUAP = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalBUAP.title = "Hospital Universitario de Puebla"
        hospitalBUAP.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.039964, longitude: -98.213331)

        let hospitalAngelopolitano = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalAngelopolitano.title = "Hospital Angelopolitano"
        hospitalAngelopolitano.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 98.213331, longitude: -98.215445)

        let hospitalUPAEP = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalUPAEP.title = "Hospital UPAEP"
        hospitalUPAEP.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.045732, longitude: -19.045732)

        let hospitalBeneficenciaEspañola = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalBeneficenciaEspañola.title = "Beneficencia Española"
        hospitalBeneficenciaEspañola.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.055711, longitude: -98.209555)

        let hospitalBetania = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalBetania.title = "Hospital Betania"
        hospitalBetania.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.034998, longitude: -98.188137)

        let hospitalVilaseca = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalVilaseca.title = "Hospital A. Vilaseca Esparza C."
        hospitalVilaseca.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.047538, longitude: -98.187644)

        let hospitalGeneralIMSS = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalGeneralIMSS.title = "IMSS San José"
        hospitalGeneralIMSS.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.050631, longitude: -98.192300)

        let hospitalGeneralZonaNorte = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalGeneralZonaNorte.title = "Hospital General Zona Norte"
        hospitalGeneralZonaNorte.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.079432, longitude: -98.184495)

        let hospitalGeneralCholula = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalGeneralCholula.title = "Hospital General Cholula"
        hospitalGeneralCholula.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.017239, longitude: -98.266399)

        let hospitalGeneralZonaSur = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalGeneralZonaSur.title = "Hospital General Del Sur"
        hospitalGeneralZonaSur.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 18.986133, longitude: -98.242405)

        let hospitalRegionalISSSTE = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalRegionalISSSTE.title = "Hospital Regional ISSSTE"
        hospitalRegionalISSSTE.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.020526, longitude: -98.197853)

        let hospitalGeneralZona20IMSS = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospitalGeneralZona20IMSS.title = "Hospital General IMSS Zona 20 La Margarita"
        hospitalGeneralZona20IMSS.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 19.008275, longitude: -98.182857)

        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalLaPaz)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalSalutem)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalPuebla)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalAngeles)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalDelNiñoPoblano)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalBUAP)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalAngelopolitano)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalUPAEP)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalBeneficenciaEspañola)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalBetania)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalGeneralIMSS)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalGeneralZonaNorte)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalGeneralCholula)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalGeneralZonaSur)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalRegionalISSSTE)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospitalGeneralZona20IMSS)
    }
}

extension MapScreen: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
       addAnnotations()
    }
}

extension MapScreen: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        let center = getCenterLocation(for: mapView)

        guard let previousLocation = self.previousLocation else { return }

        guard center.distance(from: previousLocation) > 50 else { return }
        self.previousLocation = center

        geoCoder.cancelGeocode()

        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(center) { [weak self] (placemarks, error) in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            if let _ = error {
                //TODO: Show alert informing the user
                return
            }

            guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else {
                //TODO: Show alert informing the user
                return
            }

            let streetNumber = placemark.subThoroughfare ?? ""
            let streetName = placemark.thoroughfare ?? ""

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.addressLabel.text = "\(streetNumber) \(streetName)"
            }
        }
    }


    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay as! MKPolyline)
        renderer.strokeColor = .blue

        return renderer
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearchrequest?language=objc

Comment: Thanks, I already checked it, I am relatively new to this. I would appreciate if you could explain how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

```
let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Hospital"
request.region = mapView.region

let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
search.startWithCompletionHandler { response, error in
    guard let response = response else {
        print("There was an error searching for: \(request.naturalLanguageQuery) error: \(error)")
        return
    }

    for mapItem in response.mapItems {
        // Display the received items
        let latitude = mapItem.placemark.location.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude = mapItem.placemark.location.coordinate.longitude

        let hospital = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospital.title = mapItem.name! //Only do `!` if you are sure that it isn't nil
        hospital.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        mapView.addAnnotation(hospital)
    }
}
```

Now that you have these coordinate, you can create whatever you need.

What you were doing was using the bounding box (the area of all the hospitals you found) as a location and it was providing incorrect information.

This way goes through each item found on the response and obtains their location and any other information you might need from their class `MKMapItem`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Ill try it.

Comment: I just tried it and it works perfectly, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a local search and add the results to a map, just call `addAnnotation` after you create each `MKPointAnnotation`:

```
let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Hospital"
request.region = mapView.region

let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
search.start { response, error in
    guard let response = response else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    for mapItem in response.mapItems {
        let hospital = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospital.title = mapItem.name
        hospital.coordinate = mapItem.placemark.coordinate
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(hospital)
    }
}
```

Or, of course, you could build your array of annotations and add them at the end:

```
let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
search.start { response, error in
    guard let response = response else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    let hospitals = response.mapItems.map { mapItem -> MKPointAnnotation in
        let hospital = MKPointAnnotation()
        hospital.title = mapItem.name
        hospital.coordinate = mapItem.placemark.coordinate
        return hospital
    }
    self.mapView.addAnnotations(hospitals)
}
```

---

Personally, I like having the street address there, so I’d personally also set its `subtitle` before adding the annotation:

```
hospital.subtitle = [mapItem.placemark.subThoroughfare, mapItem.placemark.thoroughfare]
    .compactMap { $0 }
    .joined(separator: " ")
```